# How to find out if audio is in use under Windows 7

Tags: c#, audio, windows-7, .net-4.0, cscore

### Basic Info

I am writing a system service for Windows 7 (and Windows Server 2008 R2) that shall gather information about the computer so that it can ultimatly be decided if the computer is in use or not.

I am using C# and .NET 4.0.

### Problem

As some people could probably use their computer just for audio playback and nothing else at some time, knowing that audio is or is not being played back at a given moment would help my cause.

I don't care about what is being played or by which application. For how long and how long ago could both be interesting, but are not essential.

Most questions and answers around audio and C# are concerned about playing audio or recording audio being played on the same machine. That makes it very difficult to search for
It would also not be enough to only know it for one application, for example Windows Media Player.

My idea rather was to hook up to the main Windows Audio Control. I'm thinking of the component, that stands behind the speaker symbol in ones taskbar. It mixes together all the sounds and thus I'd like to ask it if there is anything being played right now. Unfortunately, I have absolutely no idea how to even search for information on that topic. (I don't know if it has a special name as a component. Is this already connected to the Windows Core Audio APIs?)

Therefore any help and all new ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would it be ok to just check the peak of all audio devices?

Comment: It would definitely be something worth trying.

Comment: So you may take a look at this: http://cscore.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#CSCore.Test/CoreAudioAPI/EndpointTests.cs (take a look at the Audio Meter Tests...)

Comment: Thank you very much!
I have yet to find out if this also works when called from a system service, but it's is a very good start.

Comment: As far as I know... it should work.